# javascript output time interval

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working to automate a google sheet to google calendar, but I'm stuck.

I have an array of strings that correspond to hours

```
ex: time = [8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4]
```

and want to an output a string

```
ex: range = "8-11, 2-5"
```

I need to write this in google app script, any suggestions?

I'm new to google app script and having a hard time writing the function. My initial process was to convert the array of strings to military time integers, and create two for loops, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this.

Thanks for the help!

This is my current code:

```js
var time = [8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4]

// if (currentTime == 13) {currentTime -= 12;}
function timeRange(cellInput, hourList) {
  var start = parseInt(hourList[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < hourList.length; ++i) {
    if (hourList[i] == start + i) {
      var end = parseInt(hourList[i]);
    } else {
      cellInput.setValue(start + " - " + (end + 1));
    }
  }
}

function soloTime(cellInput, hour) {
  //convert hour string to hour
  var hour = parseInt(hour)
  var start = hour
  var end = hour + 1
  cellInput.setValue(start + "-" + end);
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Break down your problem. Do a first pass over your array to generate sequences and then transform these sequences into their respective string-based representation. It will be easier to deal with 2-element ranges that way, if you want 10, 11 instead of 10-11.

Comment: Map or reduce would be interesting methods to investigate here

Comment: I created you a snippet. Please update it so it produces (returns) a value you can console.log in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could check the predecessor and collect the ranges.

```js
var time = [8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 1],
    range = time
        .reduce((r, t, i, a) => {
            if (a[i - 1] % 12 + 1 === t) {
                r[r.length - 1][1] = t;
            } else {
                r.push([t]);
            }
            return r;
        }, [])
        .map(a => a.join('-'))
        .join(', ');

console.log(range);
```

Comment: come on it's pretty self explaining.

Comment: At least it's on multiple lines ;)))

Comment: thanks for the input! Can you explain what r, t, i, and a values represent?

Comment: `r` is the accumulator, the temporary result, `t` is the time value, `i` the index of the actual element and `a` is the array which is actually iterated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const timeToRange = (arr) => {
  const mins = arr
    .filter((x, i, arr) => x !== arr[i - 1] + 1);
  const maxs = arr
    .filter((x, i, arr) => x !== arr[i + 1] - 1)
    .map(x => x + 1);

  return mins
    .map((x, i) => [x, maxs[i]].join('-'))
    .join(', ');
};

console.log(
  timeToRange([8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4])
);
```

Comment: @mplungjan thanks! I actually wasn't familiar with that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the start of each range, then iterate until the current value does not fit to the previous, then take the previous and the start to create a range, collect them in an array, and that's it.

```
 const result = [];

 let start = time[0];
 let previous = time[0];

 // Start at the second position, and go over the arrays length by one, so tgat the last range gets added too
 for(const value of time.slice(1).concat(Infinity)) {
   // if the range isn't continuous (12 to 1 is continuous)
   if((value - previous) % 12 !== 1) {
     // Add the previous range, start the new range here
     result.push(start + "-" + previous);
     start = value;
   }
   previous = value;
}

console.log(result.join(", "));
```